# SystemCheckError (slug in django)

Tags: python, django

I got this error (what is wrong here? I can't find the root cause of this. I tried to search for this answer but it didn't applied to this case.):

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'rango.admin.CategoryAdmin'>: (admin.E027) The value of 'prepopulated_fields' refers to 'slugs', which is not an attribute of 'rango.Category'.
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Page
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slugs':('name',)}

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'category', 'url')

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have field named `slug` in your model, but you are using `slugs` in admin. You need to change it to `slug` also:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've missed this typo.